# AccessToken is null for identity server client

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

I have following openid options:

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            });



            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "oidc",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000",              
                ClientId = "mvcClient",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002",
                ResponseType = "code id_token",                            
                Scope = "openid profile",

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                    {
                        var claims_to_exclude = new[]
                        {
                            "aud", "iss", "nbf", "exp", "nonce", "iat", "at_hash"
                        };

                        var claims_to_keep =
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims
                            .Where(x => false == claims_to_exclude.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
                        claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));




                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken != null)
                        {
                            claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

   }    
  }    
 }
}
```

I see n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken is always null.

I configured client in identity server like this:

```
 new Client()
                {
                    ClientId = "mvcClient",
                    ClientName = "MVC Client",                      
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },

                   // RequireConsent = false,

                    // where to redirect to after login
                    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                    // where to redirect to after logout
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002" },

                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
                        StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
                        StandardScopes.OfflineAccess.Name,
                        StandardScopes.Roles.Name,
                        "API"
                    }
                },
```

I want to know why n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken is null and how can i get its value

**UPDATE**

If I change Client Type to Hybrid like this:

AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,

and ResponseType = "code id_token token:

I get invalid_request error on server

If I try to get access token like this (in notifications):

```
var client = new TokenClient("http://localhost:5000/connect/token", "mvcClient", "secret");
                            var response = client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("testscope").Result;
                            var accesstoken = response.AccessToken;
                            claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("access_token", accesstoken));
```

The result token has only one scope(i.e testscope) instead of all other scopes defined for that client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's null because you're not asking for an access token.

`ResponseType = "code id_token"` means give the client a "Authoriziation Code" and a "Id token" on the callback. To receive an access token,either

1. include `token` in `ResponseType` as `ResponseType = "code id_token token"` & update the client flow to Hybrid flow (code + token), since that's what we're now doing.

or

1. fetch an access token using the `/token` endpoint using the "Authorization Code" available on the `ProtocolMessage`.

Comment: as soon as I add 'token' in response type, it says unauthorize_client , i also changed client configuration to GranTypes.Hybrid on server

Comment: Yes, you would need to allow a client to use this flow (hybrid) as well - correct. Updated.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work. I updated the question as well.

Comment: Why are you calling the token endpoint using client credentials flow? You _just_ updated it to be hybrid - so you can do what I said in 2 : fetch a token using the code. 

I'd recommend some walkthrus in the idsrv docs and understand the flows.

Comment: @AsifHameed, did you get a solution to this as I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The access token should not be brought back along with code and id_token.
The right way to get it is through the back channel using client id and client secret.
Add this to the Notifications block:

```
AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
{
    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/token", "Client_Id", "secret");
    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
    {
        throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        string accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
        //Other logic
    }
}
```